# conflicting type with JlistSelectionListener

Tags: java, jlist

I have the folling code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
public class fenetre extends JFrame {
  private JList list1, list2;
//  private static String[] players1 = {"Player 1", "Player 2"};
//  private static String[] players2 = {"Player 3", "Player 4"};
  private JLabel label;
  private JPanel panel;
  private DefaultListModel model1, model2;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public fenetre(List<character> eq1,List<character> eq2) {
    super("JList Example");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    model1 = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < eq1.size(); i++) {
        model1.addElement(eq1.get(i));
      }
    List<character> lis = new ArrayList<>();
    
    list1 = new JList<String>(model1);
    list1.setVisibleRowCount(2);
    list1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    add(new JScrollPane(list1), BorderLayout.WEST);

    model2 = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < eq2.size(); i++) {
        model2.addElement(eq2.get(i));
      }
    
    list2 = new JList(model2);
    list2.setVisibleRowCount(2);
    list2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    add(new JScrollPane(list2), BorderLayout.EAST);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    label = new JLabel();
    panel.add(label);

    list1.addListSelectionListener(event -> {
          int index = list1.getSelectedIndex();
          if (index != -1) {
            // Update the label with the selected player's name
            label.setText("Selected player: " + model1.get(index).getName());
          }
        });

    list2.addListSelectionListener(event -> {
      int index = list2.getSelectedIndex();
      if (index != -1) {
        // Update the label with the selected player's name
        label.setText("Selected player: " + model2.get(index));
      }
    });

  }

  
}
```

in this section :

```
list1.addListSelectionListener(event -> {
          int index = list1.getSelectedIndex();
          if (index != -1) {
            // Update the label with the selected player's name
            label.setText("Selected player: " + model1.get(index).toString());
          }
        });
```

I'd like to replace model1.get(index).toString() with model1.get(index).getName()
model1 if filled with object of type " character " as you can see, I created this type and implemented a methode getName, yet I can't call it since it's not clear that model1.get(index) is of type character.
what can I change to make it work ?

no clear idea of what I can try to solve this

Comment: Please attach the code of `DefaultListModel`

Comment: @plplmax `DefaultListModel` is a Swing API class - look it up in the JavaDocs

Comment: `((Character)model1.get(index)).getName()` <- You need to cast the `Object` value to the expected value - note, this may fail if the model contains different types

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a VERY deep dive

The `ListModel` should contain the instances of `Character`, you should then make use of the `ListCellRenderer` API to customise the way in which the value is rendered.

You should then make use of generic constraints to restrict the `ListModel` and `JList` to only accept instances of `Character`

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) and [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

To add generic support to the `JList` and `DefaultListModel`, you can simply do...

```
private DefaultListModel<Character> model1, model2;
```

When you create the `JList`, you can then do...

```
list1 = new JList<Character>(model1);
```

Then when you want to get a `Character` out of the model, you can simply do...

```
... = model.getElementAt(index).getName();
```

Comment: well, actually @MadProgrammer response worked perfectly, using ((Character)model1.get(index)).getName() does exactly what I was looking for, but I thank your for the time you took to respond !

Comment: @Toven Generics will give you compile time protection, which will catch a lot of scenarios, where as casting the object is done at runtime, which can cause your program to crash unexpectedly - in most cases, you want to make use of generics to provide you with better protection against these issues

Comment: @Toven - Just to be crystal clear: `((Character)model1.get(index)).getName()` is a *poor* solution.  You really should not use it.  Learn about Java generics instead.